# Is it possible to get mesh vertex count in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

There are some operations I'd like to do that depend on the vertex count of a mesh. But I don't know how to find the total number of vertices.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In 3.0, you could use the *Attribute Statistic* node:

[image]

In 3.1a, there's an explicit *Domain Size* node:

[image]

Comment: Thank you my dude